# Add BINARY operator to CakePHP 3 query

Tags: mysql, cakephp, cakephp-3.0, query-builder, case-sensitive

I need a query to case-sensitive search for a string, therefore I need to add the [MySQL BINARY operator](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-binary-op.html) to the query.

I'll get an error when trying the following:

```
$listing = $this->Listings
    ->find()
    ->where([
        'BINARY Listings.title' => 'alfred'
    ]);
```

Same with:

```
$listing = $this->Listings->get($id, [
    'conditions' => [
        'BINARY Listings.title' => 'alfred'
    ]
]);
```

Is this possible with CakePHP *(seems not so)* or do I need to rewrite the query?

Comment: Whenever receiving errors, please always post the _complete_ error message including the _full_ stacktrace (ideally copied from the logs where it is available in a properly readable fashion), even if the problem might be obvious to people who are familiar with CakePHP! Also please always mention your _exact_ CakePHP version and tag your question accordingly - thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use expressions to build custom SQL. Ideally you'd create a custom expression class that could be reused and possibly transformed for portability in case you'd switch dialects (check [**`\Cake\Database\Dialect`**](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/tree/3.2.10/src/Database/Dialect)).

### Use the `CAST` function

For something quick I'd use the `CAST` function instead of the `BINARY` operator (which is an alias for that anyways), that's more portable out of the box, and easier to port further when required. Here's a basic example:

```
use Cake\Database\Expression\IdentifierExpression;
use Cake\Database\Expression\QueryExpression;

// ...

$listing = $this->Listings
    ->find()
    ->where(function (QueryExpression $exp) {
        $cast = $this->Listings
            ->query()
            ->func()
            ->cast([
                new IdentifierExpression('Listings.title'),
                'BINARY' => 'literal'
            ])
            ->tieWith(' AS ');

        return $exp->eq($cast, 'alfred');
    });
```

The generic function epression is changed to use `AS` for concatenating the arguments, so you can easily feed the function with identifier and type parts. The column is being passed as an identifier expression in order to support automatic identifier quoting, you might never need it, but it won't hurt if you don't care about a few microseconds additional compilation time.

### The `BINARY` operator

For the sake of completeness, a short example of adding the binary operator using expressions:

```
function (QueryExpression $exp) {
    $binary = $this->Listings
        ->query()
        ->newExpr()
        ->tieWith(' ')
        ->add('BINARY')
        ->add([
            'Listings.title' => 'alfred'
        ]);

    return $exp->add($binary);
}
```

This should be pretty much self-explantory, the raw string `BINARY` and the conditions will be tied together using a whitespace.

### See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Query Builder > Advanced Conditions](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#advanced-conditions)**
- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Query Builder > Using SQL Functions](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#using-sql-functions)**

Answer (score 0):

```
 $listing = $this->Listings
->find()
->where([
    'BINARY (Listings.title)' => 'alfred'
]);
```

Probably just missing brackets

[Cakephp 3 case sensitive query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37586119/cakephp-3-case-sensitive-query)