# Cakephp 3 case sensitive query

Tags: mysql, date, cakephp, cakephp-3.0, case-sensitive

```
    $date = date("Y-m-d");
    $prev_date = date('m-d-Y', strtotime($date .' -1 day'));
    $q = "SELECT `id`, `external_id`, `status`, DATE_FORMAT(from_unixtime(`created`),'%m-%d-%Y') as crt, `extras` 
            FROM `gshuplogs` WHERE DATE_FORMAT(from_unixtime(`created`),'%m-%d-%Y') = '$prev_date' and
            (BINARY `status` in ('success','DEFERRED') or `status` IS NULL)";
    $conn = \Cake\Datasource\ConnectionManager::get('default');
    $res = $conn->execute($q)->fetchAll('assoc');
    debug($res);exit;
```

The above query I have written in mysql now I just wanted to write in cakephp 3.

I have tried

```
$res = $this->Gshuplogs->find()->select([
        'id', 'external_id', 'status', 'created'
    ])->where([
        "DATE_FORMAT(from_unixtime(`created`),'%m-%d-%Y')" => $prev_date,
        'OR' => [
            ['LOWER status' => 'success'],
            ['status' => 'DEFERRED'],
            ['status IS NULL']
        ]
    ]);
```

AND

```
$res = $this->Gshuplogs->find()->select([
        'id', 'external_id', 'status', 'created'
    ])->where([
        "DATE_FORMAT(from_unixtime(`created`),'%m-%d-%Y')" => $prev_date,
        'OR' => [
            ['BINARY status' => 'success'],
            ['status' => 'DEFERRED'],
            ['status IS NULL']
        ]
    ]);
```

But it is throwing error.

> Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You
>   have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to
>   your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near
>   '**`),'%m-%d-%Y'`) = '06-01-2016' AND (`LOWER` status 'success' OR `status` =
>   'DEFE**' at line 1

Comment: What error is it throwing?

Comment: Hi @Alex here is the error..!

Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`),'%m-%d-%Y'`) = '06-01-2016' AND (`LOWER` status 'success' OR `status` = 'DEFE' at line 1

Comment: Probably just missing brackets: `['LOWER (status)' => 'success'],` cf. your error message.

Comment: Thanks @code-kobold

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your response. I got the solution.

```
    $date = date("Y-m-d");
    $prev_date = date('m-d-Y', strtotime($date .' -1 day'));

    $res = $this->Gshuplogs->find()->select([
        'id', 'external_id', 'status', "created" 
    ])->where([
        "FROM_UNIXTIME(`created`,'%m-%d-%Y')" => $prev_date,
        'OR' => [
            ['BINARY(status) in ' => ['success','DEFERRED']],
            ['status IS NULL']
        ]
    ]);

    debug($res->toArray());exit;
```